# Delete Top-N' Rows from a Table with some sorting(order by 'Column')

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having some confusion regarding Deleting the top N Rows order by some column.

I created have an example here [Example at fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1ecc/2)

What is wrong with these queries?

```
 Delete Top(3) from Table1 order by id desc

 Delete Top(3) from Table1 
 where id IN (select id from Table1 order by id desc)
```

Since in mysql the limit keyword does the job very well

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can use a CTE to do a [faster ordered delete](http://web.archive.org/web/20100212155407/http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlcat/archive/2009/05/21/fast-ordered-delete.aspx) without the need for a separate sub query to retrieve the top 3 ids.

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT TOP 3 *
         FROM   Table1
         ORDER  BY id DESC)
DELETE FROM T
```

Comment: You don't need to resort to using CTE's.  Subqueries will work just fine and generate the same Execution Plan.  `DELETE T FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table1 ORDER BY id DESC) AS T`  SQLFiddle Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a42de/30

Comment: @MikeTeeVee - why do you believe that CTEs are a "resort" and derived tables are preferable? Both will give the same execution plan. Personally I prefer CTEs for this. I find the flow preferable to read

Comment: @MartinSmith I only use them for Recursion. Aside from that, CTE's are just SubQueries and a "Code Smell" (to me).  If a Developer tells me they need CTE's to make something more readable and easier to manage, then that tells me the Query may need to be broken up into Views or Functions. It's a matter of preference, and a programming practice that has served me well.  I know I'm in the minority here and it's easier for you to read, but it drives me bonkers when I'm scrolling through pages of code (with CTE's way at the top) and trying to recall their content when I see their Aliases Joined.

Comment: I completely agree with @MikeTeeVee. The use of CTEs seems to be 'cool' for some time now.  As a developer who has been around for a few more years, I know that you can usually just wait for something like that to settle down. CTEs have their justification, e.g. for recursion - there they are great. But for 'classic' queries I find that 'normal' subqueries read much better, because the query definition is exactly where you need to understand it at that moment. I also find that subqueries are usually much more in line with the mathematical basis of relational databases (= set theory).

Comment: @Grimm - do you also believe views are not "in line with the mathematical basis of relational databases"? - I just think of non recursive CTEs as being like extremely locally scoped views. I don't understand why this would not be compatible with "mathematical basis" - both define a [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(database))

Comment: @MartinSmith Please don't read over my "usually much more".

Comment: I don't see that verbiage makes any material difference. CTEs and Derived Tables (which is the only sub query of relevance here) are both interchangeable. Mathematically there is no distinction between them - both take a SELECT expression and assign it an alias. Derived tables are just potentially less convenient in that that the same alias can't be referenced twice

Comment: OK, to clarify: I *read* sub-queries as usually being more in line with the mathematical basis of relational databases. Ultimately, of course, they are - from a mathematical point of view - interchangeable.
I often think of set theory in terms of boxes, which in turn can contain smaller boxes, and so on. When I work with subqueries, the smaller boxes are defined directly where they are viewed. With CTEs, there is a kind of indirection, so that where the smaller box is, I just find an alias to the actual definition.
But again, it's a matter of preference, not a mathematical difference.

Comment: @Grimm and I agree, "_it's a matter of preference, not a mathematical difference_".  We've both made our case against using CTE's (for non-recursion).  **What's your reasoning for why CTE's are better - _preference wise_?**  If you think of a CTE as a "_locally scoped view_", then you should consider creating a View.  I make powerfully complex Views and Functions (usually 1 per Entity) that pull in everything I'll ever need.  If I use only a few Fields of the View, then SQL will optimize automatically. This simplifies my queries to the nuts and bolts of what I need, hence more manageable code.

Answer (score 13):

Add the `top 3` clause to the subselect:

```
Delete from Table1 
where id IN (
    select top 3 id 
    from Table1 
    order by id desc
)
```

Comment: Please be extremely wary of using an `IN` which references the same table. I had a very similar query to remove 3 rows, but the `ORDER BY` was different, and it certainly did not delete 3 rows. I hadn't realised the interconnectedness.