# How delete in specific order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a column in table which reference the same table (as a parent-child relationship).

When I want to purge like this (C# Code):

```
do
{
    commandRows = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE top(5000) from IssuerRequests WHERE discriminator='IssuerRequest' and Issuer_ID = @Issuer_ID and ExpireDate < @LimitDate",
        new SqlParameter("@Issuer_ID", customer.ID), new SqlParameter("@LimitDate", LimitDate));
    AffectedRows += commandRows;
}
while (commandRows >= 5000);
```

An exception appears:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.IssuerRequests_dbo.IssuerRequests_LinkedRequestForMultichannel_ID". The conflict occurred in database "xxx", table "dbo.IssuerRequests", column 'LinkedRequestForMultichannel_ID'. The statement has been terminated.

This error is normal because if we try to delete a line referenced by another one, the system doesn't allow it.

So I manage a script in order to purge manually :

```
USE [Database]

DECLARE @DaysAfterExpiring INT
DECLARE @Issuer_ID INT
DECLARE @DateAfterExpiring DATETIME

SET @DaysAfterExpiring = 35
SET @DateAfterExpiring = DATEADD(day, -(@DaysAfterExpiring), GETUTCDATE())

SELECT @Issuer_ID = [ID] FROM IssuerDescs WHERE [DisplayName] LIKE '%toto%'

DECLARE @MoreRowsToDelete BIT
SET @MoreRowsToDelete = 1

-- With the relationship
WHILE @MoreRowsToDelete = 1
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP (1000) FROM IssuerRequests WHERE discriminator='IssuerRequest' AND Issuer_ID = @Issuer_ID AND [ExpireDate] < @DateAfterExpiring  AND LinkedRequestForMultiChannel_ID IS NOT NULL
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM IssuerRequests WHERE discriminator='IssuerRequest' AND Issuer_ID = @Issuer_ID AND [ExpireDate] < @DateAfterExpiring  AND LinkedRequestForMultiChannel_ID IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @MoreRowsToDelete = 1
    END
END

-- Without the relationship
SET @MoreRowsToDelete = 1
WHILE @MoreRowsToDelete = 1
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP (1000) FROM IssuerRequests WHERE discriminator='IssuerRequest' AND Issuer_ID = @Issuer_ID AND [ExpireDate] < @DateAfterExpiring  AND LinkedRequestForMultiChannel_ID IS NULL
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM IssuerRequests WHERE discriminator='IssuerRequest' AND Issuer_ID = @Issuer_ID AND [ExpireDate] < @DateAfterExpiring  AND LinkedRequestForMultiChannel_ID IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @MoreRowsToDelete = 1
    END
END
```

Do you know if it's possible to avoid double loops and delete 5000 lines per action without doing the distinction?

I thought about "ORDER BY" in delete with CTE but I'm not sure about the result.

I will try this possible solution :

```
USE [database]

DECLARE @DaysAfterExpiring INT
DECLARE @Issuer_ID INT
DECLARE @DateAfterExpiring DATETIME

SET @DaysAfterExpiring = 35
SET @DateAfterExpiring = DATEADD(day, -(@DaysAfterExpiring), GETUTCDATE())

SELECT @Issuer_ID = [ID] FROM IssuerDescs WHERE [DisplayName] LIKE '%toto%'

DECLARE @MoreRowsToDelete BIT
SET @MoreRowsToDelete = 1

-- With the relationship first then without the relationship
WHILE @MoreRowsToDelete = 1
BEGIN
    DELETE T FROM (SELECT TOP (1000) * FROM IssuerRequests WHERE discriminator='IssuerRequest' AND Issuer_ID = @Issuer_ID AND [ExpireDate] < @DateAfterExpiring ORDER BY ISNULL(LinkedRequestForMultiChannel_ID, '') DESC) AS T
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM IssuerRequests WHERE discriminator='IssuerRequest' AND Issuer_ID = @Issuer_ID AND [ExpireDate] < @DateAfterExpiring)
    BEGIN
        SET @MoreRowsToDelete = 0
    END
END
```

Comment: one option, if you're allowed to do it is to DROP the FKs before the DELETEs and then RECREATE then again after.

Comment: Why do you care? There is nothing wrong with a double loop. But as you say, you can order by a case expression.

Comment: It's on production env. I guess if I remove the constraint, it's for the whole system, not just the script context ?

Comment: "I thought about "ORDER BY" in delete with CTE but I'm not sure about the result." - try it and see?

Comment: I don't have any problem with double loop. Just for my culture to find another shorter way :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508280/delete-top-n-rows-from-a-table-with-some-sortingorder-by-column

Comment: I added a possible solution in my post. I can't try for now but do you think it can works ?

Comment: Why are you asking us? Try it on your staging server and see for yourself?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? How many rows do you expect to delete? There are certainly easier ways to do it. `DELETE TOP` is the *slower* way of deleting a large number of records (but not as slow as deleting one by one). If you want to delete historical records perhaps the fastest option is to use partitioning and delete or move older partitions to other tables. Another option is to use a hierarchical `SELECT` query to get IDs for the next 500-1000 *roots*, then run `DELETE .. WHERE ID in (1,6,89,...)`.

Comment: In the SELECT query you can impose an order from children to roots, or order by level, descending. This way, when you batch the IDs on the client there won't be any missing references. You can store the IDs along with the level in a temporary table or table variable too, and write a query that deletes batches in descending level order

Comment: I once had a client support issue caused by a cascade of delete triggers using cursors firing off triggers with cursors... The system became incredibly slow. Be careful with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example at the end of my original post works as attended. Because the script will delete first every lines with any FK reference, and then lines without any FK reference. I'm using batch of 1 000 lines in order to avoid to lock the table.

So the solution is to use CTE or specific query after the FROM (as comments, it's the same result) clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE to delete all of them in one go.

As long as all child rows are deleted at the same time, it works to delete them in the same statement as the child rows. There is no need for an `ORDER BY` as the server can work out that the parent and child are being deleted at the same time.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      ir.ID,
      ir.LinkedRequestForMultiChannel_ID
    FROM IssuerRequests ir
    JOIN IssuerDescs id ON id.ID = ir.Issuer_ID
    WHERE id.DisplayName LIKE '%toto%'
      AND ir.discriminator = 'IssuerRequest'
      AND ir.ExpireDate < @DateAfterExpiring

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      ir.ID,
      ir.LinkedRequestForMultiChannel_ID
    FROM IssuerRequests ir
    JOIN cte ON cte.LinkedRequestForMultiChannel_ID = ir.ID  -- is this the correct join?
)
DELETE ir
FROM cte
JOIN IssuerRequests ir ON ir.ID = cte.ID;
```

If you want to batch them then it's more complicated, as you need to make sure all the more distant levels are deleted first.

```sql
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      ir.ID,
      ir.LinkedRequestForMultiChannel_ID,
      1 AS Level
    FROM IssuerRequests ir
    JOIN IssuerDescs id ON id.ID = ir.Issuer_ID
    WHERE id.DisplayName LIKE '%toto%'
      AND ir.discriminator = 'IssuerRequest'
      AND ir.ExpireDate < @DateAfterExpiring

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      ir.ID,
      ir.LinkedRequestForMultiChannel_ID
      cte.Level + 1
    FROM IssuerRequests ir
    JOIN cte ON cte.LinkedRequestForMultiChannel_ID = ir.ID  -- is this the correct join?
)
DELETE ir
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (4500) *
    FROM cte
    ORDER BY
      cte.Level DESC
) cte
JOIN IssuerRequests ir ON ir.ID = cte.ID;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BREAK;

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

END;
```

Comment: While i agree with this answer, perhaps OP wants to actually batch the DELETEs

Comment: @siggemannen - if you add a notion of how far away from the root a given child is (which is simple - I typically add a column of `0 as [level]` to the base case and `cte.[level] + 1` in the recursive case), you can batch those deletes in such a way as to do them from leaf to root in the tree. And, I think if you do that, you're guaranteed not to run into any self-referencing FK issues even if the delete affects inhomogeneous levels.

Comment: @BenThul yes, if one saves the cte thing into a #t-table with a level, one can then do a while @@rowcount > 0 loop that deletes top 5000 order by level desc without issues

Comment: @siggemannen See edits, you need to track the level and sort by the furthest first.

Comment: @siggemannen - I don't think you need to persist the results (as Charlieface's edit shows). It is a tradeoff though - if computing the hierarchy is expensive, you'll be doing it for each run through the loop. Of course, the caveat to *that* is that the hierarchy will become smaller with each iteration so it will presumably get less expensive. As always, test and see.